# Angular theme switch using SCSS variables

Tags: angular, sass, themes

I'm trying to create Angular theme switch. I've already seen hundreds of guides about theme switch using Angular Material. I want the same but with SCSS variables.

I want to define vars at my style.scss:

```
.dark {
 $color1: #fff;
 $color2: #fff;
 $color2: #fff;
}

.light {
 $color1: #eee;
 $color2: #eee;
 $color2: #eee;
}
```

and then use these variables at components. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your  html file

Your default theme.

```
<html data-theme="light">

</html>
```

In your css file

```
html {
height: 100%;
font-family: 'Montserrat';

display: grid;
align-items: center;
justify-items: center;
--bg: #FCFCFC;
--bg-panel: #EBEBEB;
--color-headings: #0077FF;
--color-text: #333333;
```

}

```
 html[data-theme='dark'] {
--bg: #333333;
--bg-panel: #434343;
--color-headings: #3694FF;
--color-text: #B5B5B5;
```

}

Toggle based on some condition.

Comment: How would someone switch the data-theme of the tag html within the Angular environment?